# Simple Android Program Error

Tags: android

```
package com.example.enable_apps;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{

    private Runtime run;
    private String what_is_going_on="Program Started:\n";
    private TextView t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t.setText(what_is_going_on);

        run=Runtime.getRuntime();
        Thread t1= new Thread(this);
        t1.start();       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {   
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();          
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (ApplicationInfo i  : packages){
            String current_package = i.packageName;
            try {
                what_is_going_on+="\nenabling package: "+current_package;
                Log.v("string", what_is_going_on);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        t.invalidate();
                    }});                

                run.exec("su | pm enable "+current_package).waitFor();
                Log.v("enabled: ",i.packageName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                what_is_going_on+="\nerror package: "+current_package+": "+e.getMessage().toString();
                Log.v("string", what_is_going_on);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        t.invalidate();
                    }});
                Log.v("error: ",e.getMessage().toString());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                what_is_going_on+="\nerror package: "+current_package+": "+e.getMessage().toString();
                Log.v("string", what_is_going_on);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        t.invalidate();
                    }});
                Log.v("error: ",e.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i was cleaning my hard drive and i found this program and i ran it, but there was no output on screen, It only showed Program Started:
In console it was working enabling app after another, so why this happened?

Here is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    tools:context="com.example.enable_apps.MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did the emulator shown ?

Comment: When the program starts it shows, "Program started:" thats all, in logcat it shows details and then the programs also got enabled, so it was definitely working, but no output on screen :((((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there was no output on screen, It only showed Program Started:

No, the output was displayed.You seeing this because your `textView` setText with the "Program Started:"

Try add some background color to your `TextView` and you will see your `textView`.

---

To change the text in `textView`

Replace

```
private String what_is_going_on="Program Started:\n";
```

To

```
private String what_is_going_on="Hello Worldenabling package: androidenabling package: android.googleSearch.googleSearchWidget ";
```

Add all the sentences inside `""`

Comment: but then i updated the text in the thread, shouldnt the textView update too?

Comment: in the program theres this line what_is_going_on+="\nenabling package: "+current_package;

Comment: Try `what_is_going_on="HELLO WORLD"` and see.

Comment: change it to hello world in all places?

Comment: Replace `private String what_is_going_on="Program Started:\n"` to `private String what_is_going_on="Hello World"`. Then run your app, you will probably see the textView updated to `Hello World`.

Comment: yeah, that's the output :)

Comment: in logcat it gets updated properly but doesnt show on screen

Comment: how to continue in chat? i am like newbie here

Comment: what did you mean ? logcat won't display on the screen

Comment: You will only see Hello World on screen. If you want to see more things, then you have to add more widgets in your xml file.

Comment: so in the program when it enables a package the string what_is_going_on becomes >> Hello Worldenabling package: androidenabling package: android.googleSearch.googleSearchWidget i want this to be displayed on the screen

Comment: so if u change the text to textview, the textview doesnt update?

Comment: Yep! i think that t.invalidate() is a dummy function that does nothing, changed it to t.setText(what_is_going_on); and the screen populated!!